# How to create the (header) of this JSON in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

Here is the json that I am struggling to recreate. :

```
WorkLoadResult({
  "AreaReturned":[
    {
      "ResultCode":"0"
    }
  ],
  "Process":"Generic",
  "WorkLoadId":"megaupload_server_798811",
  "Status":"1",
  "TotalSuccessfulRuns":"3"
});
```

I have all of this created just perfectly in my code rolling my class into another class.  I have been attempting to create the WorkLoadResult header ( I know this really isn't a header but for lack of a better word I will call it this), but I don't see how this can even be created.  When I run this through a JSON formatter the JSON is determined to be valid.  This is something I am receiving back from a webservice.  I in turn need to have a class created in order to catch this JSON.  I have looked at multiple different json examples and see no examples that have JSON formatted in this manner with some sort of a header at the beginning of the data.

My one current option is to strip this out of the data prior to doing pushing it into a class.  I do not like this option and have to think that it is possible to have this WorkLoadResult in my class.

Quite new to JSON, any advice/direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response. If the webservice returns exactly this string and you can't tell the webservice to return plain JSON, you have no choice but removing the function call around the real JSON object.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up having to do.